# Battery charging

Tags: starter

1973 f250 with low battery.  I hooked up charger and I tried to start (probably bad idea).  Now when I turn the key all I get is buzzing noise.  Did I fry my starter?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Sounds like your battery is dead or you have a bad connection.